# jQuery - can I validate a disabled field?

Tags: jquery, validation

I've got a form where the user needs to click a link, select a user via a popup window which then populates a hidden field with  an ID and a display field with the username.

The display field is set to disabled="disabled" to force the user to use the popup and not type a value in the field.

I need to ensure the user selects a name. I'm using jQuery and Jorn's validation plugin.

Doing a required: true on the disabled field doesn't seem to fire off if the value is blank.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: If the field is just for display can't you just key off the id in the hidden? Why even use a text box for a display only field. Just use jQuery to write to a span or div. The user doesn't think they can edit the text and you aren't left trying to validate something that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Why not validate the hidden field to check it has an ID in it?

Answer (score 29):

Instead of making it disabled, have you tried making it readonly?

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" />
```

I remember from years ago that disabled fields are not submitted by forms, and hence probably are not validated

Here is the [W3C HTML4 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-readonly) on the topic.

Comment: Excellent!! I didn't even know readonly existed.. Is it compatible with all browsers?

Answer (score 3):

According to the previous suggestion the possible solution could be:

```
var _valid = $.fn.valid;
$.fn.valid = function (alsoDisabled) {
    var alsoDisabled = alsoDisabled || false;
    if (alsoDisabled) {
        this.find('[disabled]').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    var retVal = _valid.apply(this);
    if (alsoDisabled) {
        this.find('[disabled]').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    return retVal;
};
```

and so you could  call the valid method with the optional arguments:
    `$('#form').valid(true)`  to check also disabled field or
    `$('#form').valid()` for the normal behaviour

best regards
Gaetano

Answer (score 1):

why not enable it just befor validation and then disable it again...
using the `.attr('disabled','')` to enable it and then `.attr('disabled','disabled')` to disable it again it will happen so quick you wont even notice it.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code.

```
if($('#element').prop('disabled')){
   $('#element').prop('disabled', false);
   $('#element').valid();
   $('#element').prop('disabled', true);
}
```