# Show jquery validation on the field which is visible

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation

I am using jquery validation for showing error messages onmy form elements. 
I have two input fields both are email. But only one field is shown at a time( i have a link to switch between the fields).

I am hiding fields using jquery **hide and show** and also using attribute **disable** on the hidden fields. So on form submit jquery validation is kicked in only on to the first element but ev

en when the second elements is visible jquery validation is showing error only on to the first element even it is disabled and hidden. Good thing is form is throwing an error but error is not showing on the second element

Just as an place holder, here is my sample form

```js
document.ready(function() {
validator=test.my_validator({
    formId: "form",
    rules: {
        email: true
    },
    messages: {
     email: "this is required"
 }
});


 $("#show-email2").click(function() {
        //hidden element
        $(".email1").hide();
        $(".email1").value("");
        $(".email1").attr("disabled","disabled");
        //visible element
        $(".email2").removeAttr("disabled","false");
        $(".email2").show();
        
    });
    $("show-email1").click(function() {
        //hidden element
        $(".email2").hide();
        $(".email2").value("");
        $(".email2").attr("disabled","disabled");
        //visible element
        $(".email1").removeAttr("disabled","false");
        $(".email1").show();

    });
});
```

```html
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="email1"/>
    <a href="#" id="show-email2"></a>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="email2"/>
    <a href="#" id="show-email1"></a>
    
    <button type="submit"></button>
```

Comment: add your js codes as well

Comment: your `form`'s ID is `form` ? also check this link - says to enable input's, etc and to instead set it to `readonly` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329961/jquery-can-i-validate-a-disabled-field

Comment: i just added as a place holder. please ignore all the reference to id and class names.  and the link was to validate read only field. where in my case. i don't want to validate hidden fields